# Is Git-flow applicable? I think git-flow has flaw on the step merging to master before release

Tags: git, git-flow

Most people using the git-flow guide the release process after developing feature like below.

1. Merge `feature` branch to develop
2. Create a new `release` branch from the `develop`
3. Start QA on the `release` branch and commit to the `release` branch the fixs from QA. It also means the `release` version source runs on the QA env(aka. beta)
4. Merge the `release` branch to the `master` branch and tag `version` to the master branch after QA.
5. Create `hotfix` branch from the `master` branch if there is a bug in production env.

I think step 4 is harmful because there is a step to resolve conflict in it.
During resolving conflict, bugs can occur.

Someone can say that the potential conflicts should be already resolved on the `release` branch to keep merging the latest `develop` branch to the `release` branch. The `develop` branch contains the latest other release versions.

But this argument is ridiculous. In my experience, merging other features could not be accepted during QA one feature. It's even impossible to merge over and over again. In this circumstance, it is impossible to merge the `develop` branch to the `release` branch over and over again. Then, the merging from the `release` branch to the `master` branch would produce many conflicts. After that, the manual work for resolving conflicts could produce other bugs that are not found in QA. The tagging immediately after merging to `master` branch is to be hasty.

My company does production env QA normally after beta QA which is done using the `release` branch. In this circumstance, so many hotfix branches could be produced, isn't it? Not only that, I think the name `hotfix` isn't fit for this case because it is not actually released before production env QA.

**[My Idea & Suggestion]**

From this context, I think the release should be done on the `release` branch and also tagging on it. Because the `release` branch is verified during QA and there is no potential bug from merging it to another branch.

Someone can say that You're gonna get too many branches. It doesn't matter if I tag it on the commit and delete the branch.

**[Question]**

If my think is wrong or has flaws, please let me know and understand why the git-flow is better or flawless.

If you empathize with my context or agree with my thought, Is there a better idea?

Comment: I spent about a year working with git flow at my previous employer, and i don't remember having any conflicts merging releases into master. Any hotfixes done in `master` should also be present into open releases, otherwise these release branches would still have the hotfixed bug... Could you elaborate on what case would create a conflict like that?

Comment: Your statement `merge the develop branch to the release branch` is not correct. With `git-flow` you do not merge `develop` branch into `release`. You create `release` branch from `develop`. And when `release` is finished - branch is deleted. The fact that there are just 2 long-living branches with `git-flow` model (`master` and `develop`) decrease number of sources for merge conflicts. But if you will keep your `release` branch always "alive", and do merges there and back - then of course conflicts could happen.

Comment: @kosist Thanks. Your explanation let me understand the merit of the git-flow. My way that is described above makes too many live branches over and over years.